# MongoDB query to add and remove multiple object in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was struggling with this query for about three hours without results. I have this Mongoose Schema:

```
var User = mongoose.Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  surname: { type: String, required: true },
  tags: [{
     type: { type: String },
     name: { type: String }
  }, { _id: false }]
};
```

and i need to perform some manipulation on the tags array. What i need to do is to simply add and remove tags sended by the client. I have created two nested query to do that:

```
    updateTagsById: function(id, obj){
        var add = [];
        var remove = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.add.length; i++) {
            add.push({ type: obj.type, name: obj.add[i] });
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.remove.length; i++) {
            remove.push({ type: obj.type, name: obj.remove[i] });
        }
        User.update({_id: id} , { $pushAll:{ tags: add } }, function(err){
           if(err) throw err;
           User.update({_id: id} , { $pullAll: { tags: remove } }, function(err){
             if(err) throw err;
             console.log('ok');
             return true;
           });
        });
    }
```

All the function is executed without error but if i go to the mongo shell i can see that only the push query goes well. I've tried various type of  query without results. Can anyone help me understand why the second query doesn't work?

EDIT:
This is the structure about my obj object where type is a simple string and add and remove are arrays of strings.

```
var obj = {
   type: $rootScope.Modal.content,
   add: $rootScope.Modal.addCache,
   remove: $rootScope.Modal.removeCache
}
```

Comment: Need to see an example of the params `id` and `obj` that you're passing to that function

Comment: @JoshBeam The  id is the user id that is right, while obj is a object composed by three attributes: type, add and remove. All this stuff is ok,  i have tested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by changing the nested query.

```
User.update({_id: id} , { $pushAll:{ tags: add } }, function(err){
        if(err) throw err;
        User.update({_id: id} , { $pull: { tags: { name: { $in: obj.remove } } } }, function(err){
            if(err) throw err;
        });
    });
```

Now it works pretty good.